# How to find out if i set up a system alarm from activity using Implicit Intent

Tags: android

I am trying made a Simple Alarm App using this code

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

Intent i = new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM);
i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_HOUR, hour);
i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MINUTES, minute);

startActivity(i);
```

Now this code works perfectly as it open my android own alarm  and you set it up

**Now the Problem is How do I find out if my alarm is set or not**

e.g lets say when I tap Button1 it runs the above code but how do I find out if an alarm is actually been set or not

Case1: Alarm is open and you back press and come back to activity without setting up an alarm

Case2: Alarm is open and you simply press (cancel) and don't set up alarm

Case3: Alarm is open and you set up alarm and come back to activity

**SO MAINLY HOW DO I KNOW IF ALARM IS SET OT NOT**

also if possible how to I know if the alarm is latter deleted if not just forgot

**EDIT**

Thanks for the answer the answer given below is good but just one more thing as I asked before What do I do to find out if alarm is deleted later e.g I set up alarm from app and close app than i delete alarm after a while than if i open up my alarm app tomorrow i want user to know if the alarm was deleted like a text which says alarm is deleted or no alarm set

Or Simply Set the alarm As such that it cant be deleted unless you delete it from the app

Answer (score 0):

You can open intent using start activity for result policy as following way.

```
public static final int PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST=101;
startActivityForResult(pickContactIntent, PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST);

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // Check which request we're responding to
    if (requestCode == PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST) {
        // Make sure the request was successful
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            // The user has set the alarm.

        }
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            //Write your code if there's no result
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer just one more thing if u can answer plz 
What  do I do to find out if alarm is deleted later e.g I set up alarm from app and close app

than i delete alarm after a while than if i open up my alarm app tomorrow i want user to know if the alarm was deleted like a text which says alarm is deleted or no alarm set

Comment: Or Simply Set the alarm As such that it cant be deleted unless you delete it from the app

Comment: It required a more descriptive answer and we can't allow talking like this here.  So can WhatsApp me on my number +919227350852 where I can suggest you the complete solution.